# Bootstrap container being overlapped by div which is bottom fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, saas

Bootstrap container above is being overshadowed by the div below, below div is supposed to be fixed at bottom.
Below div is supposed to hold few button which should never overlap the above container which has dynamic forms.

I have formed a jsfiddle with similar problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/alowsarwar/0pz3j8f2/

```
<container>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
    Button
  </a>
  fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>  fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>

</container>

<div class="panel navbar-fixed-bottom"
         style="padding-bottom:0px; min-height:0px">
  bottom stuff
</div>
```

Comment: The normal usage of an fixed bottom or top bar is to be always top. If you doesn't want this you have to look into bootstraps `.navbar-fixed-bottom` and overwrite the specific property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the margin from the bottom div and the problem will be fixed.

```
<container>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
    Button
  </a>
  fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>  fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>

</container>

<div class="panel navbar-fixed-bottom"
         style="padding-bottom:0px; min-height:0px; margin:0;">
  bottom stuff
</div>
```

Comment: Just remove the margin from the bottom div and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: This is still overlapping the content in the above container

Comment: I think we need to get a vertical scroll for the container. Is it possible?